# Using GregorianCalendar for a custom date format

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

I need to parse a custom defined date format, defined in a device that I need to communicate where the date is given as the number of seconds counted from the year 2000.

I tried to use `GregorianCalendar` to parse this data, this is the code I tried:

```
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setGregorianChange(new Date(2000 - 1900, 0, 1));
```

The `Date` object corresponds to January 1st 2000. And I thought that with this I was fine to `setTimeInMillis` to get the correct date multiplying the time I read by `1000`, as it's counted in seconds not in miliseconds as `GregorianCalendar`, but it didn't work. I tried `setTimeInMillis(0)`, waiting that the time corresponding to `calendar` corresponds to January 1st 2000 but it doesn't, it corresponds to December 18th 1969.

How can I configure `GregorianCalendar` so I can `setTimeInMillis(0)` and it corresponds to January 1st 2000? If it's not possible, is there any other class I can use instead of creating all the code by myself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setGregorianChange` only changes the point in time where the switch from Julian to Gregorian happened. It defaults to the correct historical value.

But since pretty much everyone else out there is using proleptic Gregorian, there is a valid use case for this function:

```
setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)) //Julian never happened
```

This is also what JodaTime uses by default.

Anyway, you can just subtract `946684800000L` from the normal millisecond unix timestamp, and divide by 1000:

```
public static long secondsSince2000(Date input) {
    final long epoch = 946684800000L;
    return (input.getTime() - epoch) / 1000L;
}
```

To convert from seconds since 2000:

```
public static Calendar fromSecondsSince2000( long seconds ) {
    final long epoch = 946684800000L;
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    long timestamp = epoch + seconds * 1000L;
    cal.setTime(new Date(timestamp));
    return cal;
}
```

To see that both are working:

```
    long sec = secondsSince2000(new Date());
    Calendar cal = fromSecondsSince2000( sec );
    System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString().equals(new Date().toString()));
```

They should print `true`

Comment: The only thing in this @Esailija is that I want to convert FROM seconds since 2000 to a GregorianCalendar ;)

Comment: So, there is no need to set the timezone?

Comment: @HericDenis timestamps are instants in time... after you get the calendar you can set timezone to see whatever the time was in that timezone at a particular instant in time. For example, in Japan, when the point in time was 946684800000, it was almost noon 2000 january there but in Finland, it was 2 hours past midnight. But it was the same universal instant in time. Get it?

Comment: Okay @Esailija, understood. I have no knowledge about date formats, this was really helpfull

Comment: Well @Esailija, the last edit is okay, but I tried calendar.getTime().toString() from the Calendar fromSecondsSince2000(0), and the result is Fri Dec 31 22:00:00 BRST 1999, but I have right values to calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR); calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); Akward.

Comment: @HericDenis yes, because it was 2 hours before 2000 in your timezone (BRST) when it was 2000 in UTC. You'll see similar result with just `new Date(0).toString()`

Comment: so that's the use for seting the timezone, if I set the timezone to UTC in the GregorianCalendar I'll get the desired value.

Comment: @HericDenis yes as I explained before, you can set the timezone to whatever you want to see what time it was in that timezone in the given instant of time :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a Date to 2000/01/01 and get the time in milliseconds, then get the time in milliseconds from your device. Add the two and create Dates and Calendars to your hearts desire...

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I figured out now @Thihara, I was trying the hardest way. Thank you! I'll accept this in 4 minutes.

Comment: This doesn't cover the issue with local timezones, which I see as the only difficult part in this matter.

Comment: local timezones? Are they different from normal timezones? Sorry I'm not that familiar with them..

Comment: I mean milliseconds are absolute time and when you create a `new Date`  with year/month/day fields, you get a different millisecond value in every timezone.

Comment: Ah yes valid point if the two device and the application are in different timezones...

Comment: Well I don't see any other way than adapting a calendar and getting the timezone from the device and using those to get the proper values..

Comment: There is only one valid value for the epoch and you can easily hardcode it as a long constant... you need more information how the device works but for now the only sane thing to assume is that the device works like normal timestamps except with the epoch set to different point in time, that is, UTC 2000-1-1 00:00:00.000

Comment: guys, in my specific situation, I will not have problem with local timezones, the device is well known, it's developed here where I work and it's timezone is fixed. I just got the long value as @Thihara told me and put it in a constant. It will cover all the possible cases, for me (:

Comment: @HericDenis what are you talking about? Thihara is the only one who didn't suggest a constant, it was everyone else :D

Comment: @Esailija, I Created a Date to 2000/01/01 and got the time in milliseconds exactly as Thihara told, but with this value I created a constant because, in this case, it's really a constant x)

Comment: @HericDenis yes but did you check the constant is correct? If you created a new Date() like that, then the constant will be wrong for two reasons, because 1 is february and because it's according to the local timezone

Comment: You got a point @Esailija, now I realized that I acctualy created a GregorianCalendar and didn't use Date to initialize it, I set the fields year, day, month, etc. I tested the constant's value and it's right, when I initi a GregorianCalendar using it, it gives me the expected value :)

Comment: @HericDenis So is your constant `946684800000L`? Check it carefully, because unless you used 0 as month and UTC as timezone, you won't get that value.

Comment: my constant is 946692000000L, it's because my timezone is America/Sao_Paulo, and I set the timezones in the GregorianCalendars as this timezone. But using UTC looks like a bit better, but the result is the same. Thank you @Esailija you are really helping me!

Comment: Well, I better use UTC as we are in daylight savings!! I forgot that, man this was going wrong! Thank you again @Esailija

Comment: @HericDenis timestamps are not timezone dependent. Creating a new date with year, month etc value is timezone dependent , so when you get the timestamp value from that date, it will be wrong unless the timezone was UTC. `946692000000` is wrong value. Copypaste the timestamp value to this: http://www.epochconverter.com/ and if you see `GMT: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT` it's correct. `946684800000L` is the only correct value and has been sitting in my answer all this time...

Comment: Yeah you are totally right @Esailija, I just accepted this because this was the solution I thought in the same moment he answered, than I went coding!

Comment: Hey now thats just plain hurtful :-P And I just wrote this answer off the top of my head, it seems kinda obvious to me, I have not done much time manipulation and is not familiar with daylight saving so Esailija is correct I guess..

Comment: Sorry if you were offended, I wasn't trying to be hurtful :P

Answer (score 1):

You are using deprecated constructor for `Date`. Moreover,  you are using it wrong way.

It should be 
    GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).
according to [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

BTW why not use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)?
Then you get many handy stuff:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to change the Epoch, which is 2000/01/01 by default (Unix timestamp).
So what you want to have is simply a kind of Unix timestamp with 2000/01/01 as Epoch.

I would get the unix timestamp in millis of 2000/01/01 and save it as a constant. Now, subclass GregorianCalendar so that you can add these millis from your input data and return the correct dates.

Maybe you can also take a look at [JSR-310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)

Answer (score 0):

This would do

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")); // change the timezone as you wish
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);   
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);

cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1000); // calculate and add your millisec here where 1000 is added
```

Comment: use this method Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone zone) in the first line

Comment: In all probability OP needs UTC time.